# MySQL 6.9.8 - System.String.Substring exception when opening new connection

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, azure-worker-roles, mysql.data

Every now and then, when I'm making a database query I run into a problem with `ExecuteNonQuery` in the `MySQL.Data` library.

[image]

The exception which gets raised is this:

`Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary ("Length cannot be less than zero.")`

There are my logs from **IntelliTrace** from an **Azure Worker Role**.

It works most of the time but when this happens it stops the normal processing of the worker.

I'm loading the connection string from `app.config`, this is what it looks like:

`<add key="DatabaseConnectionString" value="Server=localhost; Port=3306; Uid=user; Pwd=mypassword; Pooling=false;" />`

I select the database at runtime with every request because it keeps changing which database it's connecting to.

Is there anything I can do to stop this from occurring and allow the new connection to open correctly?

**Edit**

Upon further investigation and crawling through the `MySQL.Data` **Source code** I've drilled down into this `getter`.

```
    [DisplayName("program_name")]
    public string ProgramName
    {
      get
      {
        string name = Environment.CommandLine;
        try
        {
          string path = Environment.CommandLine.Substring(0, Environment.CommandLine.IndexOf("\" ")).Trim('"');
          name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
          if (Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() != null)
            name = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().ManifestModule.Name;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          name = string.Empty;
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return name;
      }
    }
```

Now is it possible that the **WorkerRole** will start returning a different value for the **Environment.CommandLine** property sometime during the execution? That's what seems to be happening because it works at the beginning and then fails after a while (2-3 days.)

Comment: Please post the code snippet that contains the Substring method.

Comment: It's internal inside the MySQL.Data library. It's not my code, it's the actual MySQL code. The image shows the trace of how deep it got from me calling `ExecuteNonQuery` to all the internal methods where it crashed at the bottom

Comment: Can you reproduce this with actual data?

Comment: It's random, happens once every 2-3 days. Sometimes more often. It only ever does this on `ExecuteNonQuery` call and not `ExectueQuery` which I find weird

Comment: It may try to "substring" an empty string or null value. You will have to have a reproduction dataset.

Comment: It's failing when creating a new connection, so the actual query will be irrelevant. It's most likely recreating a new connection from the pool of connections. So the only thing it should be using is the connection string, which never changes

Comment: You can see the trace of the methods going to the bottom. It calls `GetNewOpenConnection` (pooling) then `Open`, `Create`.... `Authenticate`, `SetConnectAttrs`, `get_ProgramName`

Comment: A quick google provides me with an identical issue report: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,587913,587913#msg-587913

Comment: and http://sectarial.rssing.com/chan-2132258/all_p32.html

Comment: I've seen this article already, both links are pointing to the same article as well, not 2 different reports. Please check the content before posting as it is not helping at the minute, it's someone reporting the issue but no solution is posted

Comment: Sorry. I cannot help you further.